# How to send file by email from Firebase Storage ObjectMetadata

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, storage

I am developing a trigger function that listens for a new object in the bucket specified. What I want is to send the object returned by email using nodemailer.

```
const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: "xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com",
    pass: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  }
});

exports.sendConfirmationEmail = functions.storage.bucket('bucket-name').object().onFinalize(async (object) => {
  const orderID = object.name.slice(0, -4);
  admin.database().ref('/pedidos/' + orderID).once('value', (snapshot) => {
    return sendEmail(snapshot.val().customer, snapshot.val().email, snapshot.val().number, /*FILE*/);
  });
});

function sendEmail(user, email, order, file){
  console.log("Sending Email...");
  return transport.sendMail({
      from: "XXXXXX <xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com>",
      to: email,
      subject: "Confirmación pedido " + order,
      html: `
            <h1> Estiamdo ${user}, </h1>
            <p> Hemos recibido su pedido correctamente. Le mantendremos infromado de su estado. </p>
            <p> Gracias por confiar en nosotros </p>
          `,
      attachment: file
    })
    .then(r => r)
    .catch(e => {
      console.log("An error has ocurred " + e);
    });
  }
}
```

Please can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let's fix up the main part of your Cloud Function. When writing code for your functions, as a general rule, don't use the callback API of the Admin SDK.

```
admin.database().ref('/pedidos/' + orderID).once('value', (snapshot) => { /* ... */ });
```

should be

```
admin.database().ref('/pedidos/' + orderID).once('value')
  .then((snapshot) => { /* ... */ });
```

or

```
const snapshot = await admin.database().ref('/pedidos/' + orderID);
```

It's also very important to make sure that you `return` or `await` any promises in your event handler, otherwise your code could be terminated at any time resulting in unexpected errors.

As you are only sending PDF documents, we'll ignore any files that are not PDFs.

```
exports.sendConfirmationEmail = functions.storage.bucket('bucket-name').object().onFinalize(async (object) => {
  if (object.contentType !== "application/pdf")
    return; // ignore non-pdfs
  
  const orderID = object.name.slice(0, -4);

  // ↓↓ this return is needed
  return admin.database().ref('/pedidos/' + orderID).once('value')
    .then((snapshot) => {
      return sendEmail(snapshot.val().customer, snapshot.val().email, snapshot.val().number, /*FILE*/);
    });
});
```

Next, we move on to your `sendEmail` function. In your current `sendEmail` function, you incorrectly use `attachment` instead of [`attachments`](https://nodemailer.com/message/). You can also remove these lines that will just introduce problems:

```
.then(r => r) // doesn't do anything
.catch(e => { // logs an error, but incorrectly prevents it being handled by .catch() elsewhere
  console.log("An error has ocurred " + e);
});
```

This allows us to redefine `sendEmail` as:

```
function sendEmail (user, email, order, attachments = undefined) {
  return transport.sendMail({
    from: "XXXXXX <xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com>",
    to: email,
    subject: "Confirmación pedido " + order,
    html: `
          <h1> Estiamdo ${user}, </h1>
          <p> Hemos recibido su pedido correctamente. Le mantendremos infromado de su estado. </p>
          <p> Gracias por confiar en nosotros </p>
          `,
    attachments
  });
}
```

Next, let's review the documentation for the [`attachments` property](https://nodemailer.com/message/attachments/):

> `attachments` option in the message object that contains an **array of attachment objects**.
>
> Attachment object consists of the following properties:
>
> - `filename` - filename to be reported as the name of the attached file. Use of unicode is allowed.
> - `content` - String, Buffer or a Stream contents for the attachment
> - `path` - path to the file if you want to stream the file instead of including it (better for larger attachments)
> - `href` – an URL to the file (data uris are allowed as well)
> - `httpHeaders` - optional HTTP headers to pass on with the href request, eg. `{authorization: "bearer ..."}`
> - `contentType` - optional content type for the attachment, if not set will be derived from the filename property
> - `contentDisposition` - optional content disposition type for the attachment, defaults to ‘attachment’
> - `cid` - optional content id for using inline images in HTML message source
> - `encoding` - If set and content is string, then encodes the content to a Buffer using the specified encoding. Example values: ‘base64’, ‘hex’, ‘binary’ etc. Useful if you want to use binary attachments in a JSON formatted email object.
> - `headers` - custom headers for the attachment node. Same usage as with message headers
> - `raw` - is an optional special value that overrides entire contents of current mime node including mime headers. Useful if you want to prepare node contents yourself

Now we know what we can use for each attachment object, we need to compare that list against what we can extract from the [`object`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_storage_.objectmetadata) parameter passed into the [Storage Event Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events) event handler. The main properties include:

```
const fileBucket = object.bucket; // The Storage bucket that contains the file.
const filePath = object.name; // File path in the bucket.
const contentType = object.contentType; // File content type.
const metageneration = object.metageneration; // Number of times metadata has been generated. New objects have a value of 1.
```

So, for our attachment, we want to provide `filename`, `content`, `contentDisposition` and `contentType`. Because the Cloud Storage object we are sending isn't located on disk or in memory, we are going to stream it from Cloud Storage through to `nodemailer` by passing a `Stream` as the `content` property of our attachment object. This results in:

```
const bucket = admin.storage().bucket(object.bucket);
const remoteFile = bucket.file(object.name);

const attachment = {
  filename: `order-${orderID}.pdf`,       // the attachment will be called `order-<ID>.pdf`
  content: remoteFile.createReadStream(), // stream data from Cloud Storage
  contentType: object.contentType,        // use appropriate content type
  contentDisposition: "attachment",       // this file is a downloadable attachment
};
```

We can now roll it all together and clean it up with `async`/`await` syntax:

```
const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({ /* ... */ });

exports.sendConfirmationEmail = functions.storage.bucket('bucket-name').object().onFinalize(async (object) => {
  if (object.contentType !== "application/pdf") {
    console.log("Content-Type was not application/pdf. Ignoring.");
    return; // ignore non-pdfs
  }

  // if (object.metageneration > 1) {
  //   console.log("Metageneration was greater than 1. Ignoring.");
  //   return; // ignore rewritten files
  // }
  
  try {
    const orderID = object.name.slice(0, -4);

    const orderSnapshot = await admin.database()
      .ref(`/pedidos/${orderID}`)
      .once('value');

    if (!orderSnapshot.exists) {
      console.error(`Order #${orderID} document not found`);
      return;
    }

    const { customer, email, number } = orderSnapshot.val();

    // prepare attachment
    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket(object.bucket);
    const remoteFile = bucket.file(object.name);

    const attachment = {
      filename: `order-${orderID}.pdf`,       // override name of the PDF
      content: remoteFile.createReadStream(), // stream data from Cloud Storage
      contentType: object.contentType,        // use appropriate content type
      contentDisposition: "attachment",       // this file is a downloadable attachment
    };

    console.log("Sending confirmation email...");
    await sendEmail(customer, email, number, [ attachment ]);

    console.log(`Email confirmation was sent successfully for Order #${orderID}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Unexpected error: ", error);
  }
});

function sendEmail (user, email, order, attachments = undefined) {
  return transport.sendMail({
    from: "XXXXXX <xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com>",
    to: email,
    subject: "Confirmación pedido " + order,
    html: `
          <h1> Estiamdo ${user}, </h1>
          <p> Hemos recibido su pedido correctamente. Le mantendremos infromado de su estado. </p>
          <p> Gracias por confiar en nosotros </p>
          `,
    attachments
  });
}
```

**Note:** You should decide if the email should be sent or not when `metageneration` is greater than 1.

**Addendum:** I highly recommend using [`functions.config()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env) to store things like username/password combos for `nodemailer` rather than write them into your code.

Comment: What a fantastic answer